# Derivative of a function w.r.t. another function.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

### [image: W|A calculation link]

How is this? I'm getting $(-\tan(x))$. Here's my attempt:

Let $u=\sin(x)$ and $v=\cos(x)$. Then, the derivative we seek is,

> $$\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm du}$$

Using chain rule, we have,

$$\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm du}=\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dx}\cdot \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm du}=(-\sin(x))\cdot\frac{1}{\cos(x)}=(-\tan(x))$$

---

I can't find my flaw. Please help.

---

[Here's](http://bit.ly/1TGucvO) the W|A link (shortened by Bit.ly) if anyone wants to verify.

Comment: dx/du is not quite the same as the reciprocal of du/dx.

Comment: @Nitin, please provide sources to support your claim. Also, can you post an answer as to how one can manually get the answer as $\cot(x)$ ?

Comment: @tom_cruise It's a basic differentiation rule. If I have the function $y=x^2$, then $y'=2x$, and $x'=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}$; the two are not inverses.

Comment: @HDE226868, it'd be better if you can tell me something to help with my problem.

Comment: @tom_cruise That *is* your problem, as Nitin and mathers101 said. I'm just giving another example to show the point. You already have an answer that can take you the rest of the way.

Comment: @HDE226868, the answer that has been posted tells me that W|A is wrong, which can't be true. There needs to be some other reason.

Comment: @tom_cruise Scratch that. My bad there, I missed something.

Comment: Actually, HDE, in your example, we see $x'=\frac{1}{2\sqrt y}=\frac{1}{2x}=\frac{1}{y'}$, so it does hold.

Comment: WA is interpreting the $d$'s as parameters.  So the application views $d \cos x/d\sin x$ as $d \times \cos x$ divided by $d \times \sin x$, which is $\cot x$.  Your answer is fine.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

WA interprets the $d$ as a constant, so they cancel out. The resulting fraction, $\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}=\cot x$.

Comment: Damn! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Wish I had made that comment.  ;-))

Answer (score 8):

To do the calculation a more plausible way,
$$ \frac{d}{d\sin{x}}\cos{x} = \frac{d}{d\sin{x}}\sqrt{1-\sin^2{x}} = \frac{d}{dy}\sqrt{1-y^2}, $$
by writing $y=\sin{x}$ (mere replacement of symbols, doesn't mean anything more)
$$ \frac{d}{dy}\sqrt{1-y^2} = -\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} = -\frac{\sin{x}}{\cos{x}} = -\tan{x}, $$
so your answer is correct.

My guess is that W|A is misinterpreting your input: for example, [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7Bd%7D%7Bd%28y%29%7D%28y%5E2%29) doesn't do what you would expect either. It's probably just interpreting $d$ as a constant, so it thinks it is just doing fraction arithmetic.

Comment: I think you meant $(-\tan x)$ and not $(-\cot x)$. Anyway, thank you! I can't accept both answers so I'm upvoting this one instead. :)

Comment: Ah yes, thank you.

Comment: This is perhaps _plausible_, but such calculations should always be taken with care. “Derivative of a function WRT another function”, as such, doesn't really make any sense unless the latter is explicitly a function of a function (i.e. a functional). $\cos$ is not really a functional, it's just a real-valued function.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Agreed, although it should hold whenever the chain rule does (that being essentially what I have used, although I have not said so explicitly).

Answer (score 3):

To find $\frac{dx}{du}$ we see $x=\arcsin u$. Then,

$$\frac{dx}{du}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2 x}}=\frac{1}{\cos x}$$

so that step isn't wrong like Nitin said. I don't see why your solution is wrong, I'd love to see insight anybody else has.

As some others have said, W|A must just be canceling the $d$'s. Your answer is A-okay!!